# Adding paths/vector lines to a 3D model

Tags: modeling, objects, import

I am a surveyor looking to use drone generated point clouds or 3D pdf's of a landscape and add a visual path or vector to demonstrate an official route through the modelled landscape.

Does Blender allow for the import of a las or 3D PDF simplified mesh file which can then have the path added to it?

I am a beginner to this type of modelling so please bear it in mind when answering!

Many thanks

Comment: No, Blender will not be able to import 3d pdfs out of the box. It does however support a number of [other 3d exchange formats](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/files/import_export.html#importing-exporting-files).